# Is there a way to set a default solution .runsettings file in VS2013?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm using VS2013 with the built-in unit test framework.  I've created a .runsettings file that sits in the Solution Items folder.  When I select Test -> Test Settings -> Select Test Settings File, I am able to choose my .runsettings file and it works as expected.

When I exit out of VS2013 and then re-load the project, I have to re-select the .runsettings file.  Is there any way to set the default .runsettings file at solution level so it gets persisted?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx, by selecting the .runsettings file you created using the menu options you have indicated, you should not have to keep selecting it each time you restart Visual Studio.

The docs do warn about using the SettingsFile option:
"If you specify this value, you must also set the ForcedlegacyMode to true."

Make sure you are using the latest update to Visual Studio 2013 (Update 1).  Also, you can try resetting your IDE settings through Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.

Answer (score 2):

If you open test explorer quickly enough while the solution is loading, it will remember the file. I tested this in VS 2013 SP 3 with a native c++ unit test project. It appears to be a [known bug](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c5ccee4a-83d7-4f6d-bb0e-d27c591bc2ce/setting-default-runsettings-file?forum=vsunittest).